# How do I access the return data from a FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-futurebuilder

I am having a trouble accessing a single data from Firestore. Since accessing data from Firestore is a future whenever I try to call it from initState and setState it, it just prints `null` so I decided to use a FutureBuilder. So now, is it possible to access the return data from a FutureBuilder to the another page from `page1.dart` to `page2.dart`?

page1.dart

```
class FetchSingleData extends StatelessWidget {
  // I want to access this one
  String? uniqueHandler;

  FetchSingleData({super.key, this.uniqueHandler});

  Future<QuerySnapshot> fetchUniqueHanlder() async {
    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get().then((value) => uniqueHandler = value.docs.first['userUniqueHandle']);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchUniqueHanlder(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           // I want to access this one
            return Text(uniqueHandler!);
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        });
  }
}
```

here is the snippet/image of my firebase firestore.
[image]

I just wanna access the `userUniqueHandler` from my FutureBuilder(page1.dart) to my MainScreen(page2.dart)

Comment: The output of a FutureBuilder is a widget, not a data structure.  If you need to use the data in multiple places, you should manage the state through a package like Riverpod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `snapshot` itself contains the data:

try this:

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> fetchUniqueHanlder() async {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').get();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: fetchUniqueHanlder(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
      if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Text("error");
      }

      final users = snapshot.data!;

      // your value
      uniqueHandler = users.docs.first['userUniqueHandle'];

      return Text(uniqueHandler!);
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: if you're using this in multiple pages it's best to use a state manager